# Regular expression within count() of a list not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to count certain expressions in tokenized texts. My code is:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
print(tokens.count(r"<cash><flow>"))
```

'tokens' is a list of tokenized texts (partly shown below). But the regex here is not working and the output shows 0 occurrence of 'cash flow', which is not correct. And I receive no error message. If I only count 'cash', it works fine.

```
'that', 'produces', 'cash', 'flow', 'from', 'operations', ',', 'none', 'of', 'which', 'are', 'currently', 'planned', ',', 'the', 'cash', 'flows', 'that', 'could', 'result', 'from'
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Try counting separately then.

Comment: @LukStorms  pls see the input of tokens added above

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  in my case, actually I need to count them together becz 'cash' and 'flow' will surely appear somewhere else separately

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample, including the value of the `raw` text? Thanks!

Comment: Is it accurate to assume that there will never be any space characters separating `<cash>` from `<flow>`? Also, without sample input that reproduces the error we are left to guess, which is not an efficient way to arrive at an answer.

Comment: @alecxe my {raw} text is extracted from a html file using get_text() in BeautifulSoup, and it is very large

Comment: @DavidO  your point is correct. Actually I found I cannot use <> within count(), <> can only be used in findall() of tokenied texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this.
Just the find the matching keywords in tokens and count the elements.

Example:

```python
tokens = ['that','produces','cash','flow','from','operations','with','cash']
keywords = ['cash','flow']

keywords_in_tokens = [x for x in keywords if x in tokens]
count_keywords_in_tokens = len(keywords_in_tokens)

print(keywords_in_tokens)
print(count_keywords_in_tokens)
```

count_keywords_in_tokens returns 2 because both words are found in the list.

To do it the regex way, you need a string to find the matches based on a regex pattern.
In the example below the 2 keywords are separated by an OR (the pipe)

```
import re

tokens = ['that','produces','cash','flow','from','operations','with','cash']
string = ' '.join(tokens)

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(cash|flow)\b', re.IGNORECASE)

keyword_matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
count_keyword_matches = len(keyword_matches)
print(keyword_matches)
print(count_keyword_matches)
```

count_keyword_matches returns 3 because there are 3 matches.